I'm using Django ImageField but I can't access the images in my web page
this is models.py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Products(models.Model):
    name_product=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category_product=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price_product=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image_product=models.ImageField(default='Image.png',upload_to='web/')
    description_product=models.CharField(max_length=400)

this is views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Products

# Create your views here.

def asli(request):
    data=Products.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'data':data})


this is my web page
<img src="{{ data.image_product.url }}" alt="Product Image">

I tried this code in the setting.py but still it doesn't show my photos on my web page
P.s: The connection has been established correctly
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media"


data contains many products. so as artin said you want to loop the data. {% for item in data %}{{ item.image_product.url }}{% endfor %}

@christopherjohnsonmccandless that is not enough because the files are not hosted on any available URL.

1. You have to ensure that your media files are served on the given MEDIA_URL as Django will not handle that for you. You may use the local Django server since you are still in DEBUG mode.
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [•••Rest of code•••]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    ]
2. data is a QuerySet. You have to iterate over it before you can get each value within. See for template tag.
{% for product in data %}
    <p>{{ product.name_product }} </p>
    <p>{{ product.category_product }} </p>
    <p>{{ product.price_product }} </p>
    <img src="{{ product.image_product.url }}" alt="{{ product.name_product }}" />
    <p>{{ product.description_product }} </p>
{% endfor %}

you need to add url to get the link {{ product.image_product.url }}

If you put your <img> in a block like this:
{% for item in data %}

{% endfor %}

where you write item after for, then you need to change {{ data.image_product.url }} into {{ item.image_product.url }}.

1. Configure urls.py
Ensure that you add the following configuration in your main urls.py file to serve media files
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatters = [
    # url
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

2. Update Your Template
In your template, you can fetch and display images using the following example. Ensure you use the URL attribute of the image field to get the correct path to the image.
{% for i in data %}
    <p> {{ i.name_product }} </p>
    <p> {{ i.category_product }} </p>
    <p> {{ i.price_product }} </p>
    <img src="{{ i.image_product.url }}"/>
    <p> {{ product.description_product }} </p>
{% endfor %}

Note: Make sure to add the URL while fetching the image {{i.image_product.url }}
